# add CC to sharepoint task

Tags: workflow, email, tasks

Is there any way to assign a person/group to be CC'd on a sharepoint task, so they get the same notifications as the assigned user?

I have a custom workflow where I create tasks, and an administrator wants to be CC'd on all the task notifications.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the past when I have gotten this request I've setup a simple email notification step either right before or in parallel with the task assignment.  This can ensure that people are notified that a task has been assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a SPD or VS workflow?

In Visual Studio for the SendEmail activity there is an option in properties window for you to enter information for CC

--> click the ellipses, click the "Bind to a new member" tab, remove the 1 from the end of the "New member name" and click OK